# How can I replace characters in a string without using String Buffer class replace() method?

Tags: java

I need to make replace method that replaces the characters between start(inclusive) and end(exclusive, i.e. characters up to index end-1 will be replaced) in this TextLine with characters in the specified string fragment. I can not directly or indirectly use StringBuffer Class replace(int start, int end, String fragment) method. I'm trying to make the eLine.replace(0, 3, "abc"); or eLine.replace(0, 3, "abc"); work.

I tried to make a replace method similar to StringBuffer Class but it didn't work out. I can't think of another way to make a replace like that which is why I'm stuck. If there is another way, please show me an example or solution.

```
public int length;
public char[] characters;

public class TextLineTester {
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a line of text.");
     String text = input.nextLine();
     EditableTextLine eLine = new EditableTextLine(text);
     Scanner strCharsInput = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter string of characters.");
     String str = strCharsInput.nextLine();
     eLine.replace(0, 3, "abc");
     eline.replace(0, str.length(), "abc"); // suppose to replace all occurrences of string eLine with the string ”abc”and print the modified eLine
     System.out.println(eLine.toString());
  }  
}

public void replace(int start, int end, String fragment) {
     if (end > length) {
        end = length;
     }

     int fragmentLength = fragment.length();
     int newLength = length + fragmentLength - (end - start);
     ensureCapacityInternal(newLength);
     System.arraycopy(characters, end, characters, start + 
                                           fragmentLength, length - end);
     fragment.getChars(0,0, characters, start);
     length = newLength;
}

public EditableTextLine(String line) { // creates EditableTextLine object
   length = line.length();
   characters = new char[DEFAULT_SIZE * 2];
   characters = line.toCharArray();
}

public String toString() {
   return "Characters: " + new String(characters);
}
```

}

```
This is the error I get from this current replace method. 
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at edu.uga.cs1302.txtbuff.EditableTextLine.replace(EditableTextLine.java:109)
    at edu.uga.cs1302.test.TextLineTester.main(TextLineTester.java:36)


 Input: ABCDEFG
 After  eLine.replace(0, 3, "abc"), Output will be 
 Output: abcBCDEFG


 Another example:
 Input: AB678CDEFGHIJK12345
 eLine.replace(2,5,”XY”);  // line is now ”ABXYCDEFGHIJK12345”
```

Comment: `String` is immutable. So you'll need to return the new value and assign it somewhere. This also looks like more code than you should need to perform a `replace`. Take the substring before your initial match, take the substring after and your replacement value; join the three parts together.

Comment: Sounds like homework, which you should do entirely yourself to get the most out of it. However, cold you add some examples of input and output, because I for one don't understand exactly what the task is. Does it chop off the input string at position 3 and add "abc", or is the intention to replace all chars after 3 with chars cycling through "abc"? Examples speak clearer and louder than words.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll edit an example, and yes it is homework. I tried to find a solution but unfortunately, I have not been successful. So, I am here now just asking for some help or some tips on how to get replace method going. It is suppose to chop off the input string at whatever the position is and add the "abc" string.

Comment: If this is homework, say so.

Comment: Oh alright, gotcha, my bad. I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an isolated method to take any string and make the replacement, this would be the easiest.

```java
   public static String replace(String orig, int start, int end, String replace) {
      String front = orig.substring(0,start);
      String back = orig.substring(end);
      return front + replace + back;
   }
```

I intentionally omitted using `StringBuilder`.  This should be easy to adapt to a homegrown "String" class.